# How to target all elements with Jquery on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Only first element getting clicked not all, how to get alert on all elements.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".box i");

btn.onclick = function () {
  alert('hello');
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: You do realize that there is no jQuery use in that code, nor the answer you accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try querySelectorAll for select all then attract onclick to all element

```js
var btnlist = document.querySelectorAll(".box i");
btnlist.forEach(element =>{element.onclick = function () {
  alert('hello');
}});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box">
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the title of the question, you don't currently use jQuery in your code. So, I provide 2 solutions:

**jQuery**:

```js
jQuery('.box i').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

**Pure JS**

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // or e.target.classList.contains('fa-address-book-o')
    if (e.target.className === 'fa fa-address-book-o') { // Better to add some additional class to identify element, like "fireAlert" for instance.
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could select icons with query selector and add individual event listeners to all of them in a loop, but it's bad for performance & generally not considered a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it only work on the first element is that using [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method will select only the first element the meet your selector criteria, to be able to select all the elements you have to use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which can iterate through like this:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".box i");

btns.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.onclick  = function () {
    console.log(`Hello! ${i}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true">1</i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true">2</i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true">4</i>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true">5</i>
</div>
```